# Need a theoretical explanation about the Cartographer's file, especially the function CairoPaintSubmapSlices and the function PaintSubmapSlices

Tags: ros2, slam

Need a theoretical explanation about the Cartographer's file [submap_painter.cc](https://github.com/ros2/cartographer/blob/ros2/cartographer/io/submap_painter.cc), especially the function ***CairoPaintSubmapSlices*** and the function ***PaintSubmapSlices***.

I understand that a big map contains a lot of sub-maps. The two functions mentioned above try to paste sub-maps together so we can get a complete map.

There is a ROS message called **[submap_list](https://github.com/ros2/cartographer_ros/blob/ros2/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/SubmapList.msg)** that contains a field called **[pose](https://github.com/ros2/cartographer_ros/blob/ros2/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/SubmapEntry.msg)**. The **[pose](https://github.com/ros2/cartographer_ros/blob/ros2/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/SubmapEntry.msg)** seems like indicate the origin of the sub-map in the word coordinate. We can consider it as a transformation matrix T1. Additionally, there also has a field called the **[slice_pose](https://github.com/ros2/cartographer_ros/blob/ros2/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/SubmapTexture.msg)** of texture. We can get it by calling the service **[SumbapQuery](https://github.com/ros2/cartographer_ros/blob/ros2/cartographer_ros_msgs/srv/SubmapQuery.srv)**. It seems can change the pixel coordinate of the submap to the local coordinate of the submap. Let's consider it T2.

But what we want is the pixel coordinate of the complete map. By knowing this, we can paste the pixels of the sub-map into a big complete map.

I know the function **CairoPaintSubmapSlices** and the function **PaintSubmapSlices** can do the job; however, I cannot understand exactly how.

By the way, there can be a lot of textures in the response of the service SumbapQuery. Why do we only want the first texture? What is the usage of the other textures?

There are two fields of **submap_version**. One is in the message of **[submap_list](https://github.com/ros2/cartographer_ros/blob/ros2/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/SubmapList.msg)**; the other is in the response of the service **[SumbapQuery](https://github.com/ros2/cartographer_ros/blob/ros2/cartographer_ros_msgs/srv/SubmapQuery.srv)**. What is the difference between the two versions?

I try to read the code; however, it uses a lot of Cairo library. It will be much easier if I have a theoretical explanation about how the sub-maps are been merged.